# Laravel Soft Delete Not working in pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, many-to-many, soft-delete

I am using Laravel 5.2.

I have 3 tables: `book`, `user` and `book_user` (the pivot table).

I  want to use soft deletes on my pivot table.  When I `attach` a book to a user, the relationship is inserted into the `book_user` table.  However when I `detach` this relationship, the record in the pivot table is deleted even though I added `use SoftDeletes` to the pivot table model.

How can I implement soft deletes for the records in my pivot table when I `attach` or `detach`?

Answer (score 4):

I didn't try it using soft delete with pivot table but you're saying that it doesn't work.

Just an idea, maybe you can use `sync` instead of `detach` like this;

Before that you need to add `deleted_at` column to `book_user` table as `DATETIME` instead of `TIMESTAMP`. Because new version of MYSQL doesn't support `NULL` for `TIMESTAMP` type.

**Soft Deleting**

```
$user->books()->sync(array(1 => array('deleted_at' => DB::raw('NOW()'))));
```

**Getting**

Also you can put a constraint on the Eager Load:

```
public function books()
{
    return $this
    ->hasMany('Book')
    ->whereNull('book_user.deleted_at');
}
```